# React-infinite-scroll - Error : Uncaught TypeError: this.getDOMNode is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I trying to implement react-infinite-scroll, It should render 10 element first time, then on scroll it should load more elements, Here is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

var App=React.createClass({

    getInitialState(){
        var a=[];
        for(var i=0;i<300;i++){
            a.push(i);
        }
        return ({ data:a,entry:[],hasMoreItems: true,start:1,end:50 })
        },

     loadItems: function(page) {
        this.setState({entry:this.state.data.slice(this.state.start,this.state.end)});
        console.log("entry state",this.state.entry);    
        if(this.state.data.length==this.state.end){
            this.setState({hasMoreItems:false})
        }
        this.setState({start:this.state.start+50});
        this.setState({end:this.state.end+50});
        },

    render(){
        var items = [];
        this.state.entry.map((track, i) => {
            items.push(
                <div className="track" key={i}>
                    <div key={i}>HI {i}</div>
                </div>
            );
        });

        console.log("items",items)

        return(

        <InfiniteScroll
        pageStart={0} 
        loadMore={this.loadItems} 
        hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems} 
        loader={<div className="loader">Loading ...</div>} 
        >
  <div>
  {items}
        </div> 
</InfiniteScroll>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The entry state is changing on scroll but component is not rendering again Its only displaying first 50 datas.

Please Help

Comment: Note: `hasMore` will always be true...

Comment: This is because your version is outdated. Use [the new version](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller) because the function has changed from `this.getDOMNode` to `findDOMNode`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have installed new version, Now on Scroll its calling loadItems function and in function its changing entry state, But it is not render new data. please help